# Saving an SVM as an exportable file

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, opencv, computer-vision

In my iOS project I have to train an SVM in opencv2 with a large set of images (~40,000).  This SVM is static (just train it once with no additional learning). Obviously, this takes a long time to run.  I was wondering if there's any way to train this SVM once and then save it to an exportable file that I can drag into projects and load (without having to train) as like a plist or a .txt.  I looked at wrapping it as an object in an NSArray and using writeToFile:atomically: but I couldn't get it to work.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can save it into a XML file, which can keep SVM's structure pretty well. And if you are using any SVM library, usually they have functions to save/load the model.

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find any solution? I tried using SVM's save/load functions but its not working.